# Remove spaces from SHA1 within a FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to print out each of the SHA1 hashes for all of the executables within a given directory using a .bat file. I plan to run a different command than echo, but I can not get it to remove the spaces. I want it to run the given command that uses the SHA1 as an attribute on the actual command, but I need to remove the spaces. The code originally wrote the executable name and SHA1 to a csv, but I am trying to cut the middle step out.

```
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
     'dir "%testfolder%\*.exe" /s /b /a-d'
) Do If %%~sA Gtr 0 For /f "delims=" %%B in (
     'certutil -hashfile %%A SHA1 ^|findstr /i ^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f].[0-9a-f][0-9a-f].[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]'
) Do (
     REM I want to print the SHA1 number without the spaces
     Echo %%B
)
```

I have tried creating a second variable so that the last Do looks like this:

```
Set var=%%B
Set var=%var: =%
Echo %%var
```

But that does not get the desired result either. Any suggestions?

Comment: User @dbenham wrote a really nice hash script on [Dostips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7592).

Comment: `echo %%var` is wrong, it must read `echo %var%`; `%%B` is a meta-variable of a `for` loop while `%var%` is an environment variable. Anyway, when you try to do this inside of a loop, it still doesn't return wnat you want, unless you use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), so it's goint to be `echo !var!` then...

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example commands to help you out.

Without delayed expansion:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/S/A-D "%testfolder%\*.exe" 2^>Nul'
)Do If %%~sA Gtr 0 For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('CertUtil -HashFile "%%A" SHA1^
 ^|Find /V ":"') Do Set "SHA1=%%B"&Call Echo(%%SHA1: =%%
Pause
```

…and with delayed expansion, *(recommended if you have many executables in the directory)*:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/S/A-D "%testfolder%\*.exe" 2^>Nul'
)Do If %%~sA Gtr 0 For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('CertUtil -HashFile "%%A" SHA1^
 ^|Find /V ":"')Do SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&Set "SHA1=%%B"^
 &Echo(!SHA1: =!&EndLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found something that works.

```
set d=%%~B
set e=!d!
set e=!e: =!
set desiredcommand=command !e!
!desiredcommand!
```

I am still learning the syntax and whatnot of batch scripting, so I am not familiar with what the differences are between using % and ! to surround a variable when I keep seeing it both ways. Thank you all for your help and advice.